# Sudden burst in free memory

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

I'm experiencing some strange memory management behaviour on Squeeze with Kernel 2.6.  I'm trying to get to the bottom of this with nmon.

Sometimes this will freeze up the system for 30 seconds to 5 minutes.

The server has 4GB of RAM.

The figures from nmon are:

- +1.6GB memfree.
- cached dropped by ~350MB
- swapcached dropped by ~80MB
- swap free jumped by ~200M
- active memory dropped by ~1.3GB

When this happens, the server isn't near any limits.  Very soon after it happens, the active memory creeps back up, along with cached... and naturally memfree drops.

This doesn't appear to be a runaway process.  The OS just seems to reallocate a bunch of ram very suddenly, then it slowly reallocates it back.  Swappiness shouldn't be a factor because swap is barely ever touched.

Is there any way to track what is happening?  Why does this free memory suddenly appear in seconds, only to be given back to the cache within 30 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it was a DoS.  Some 60 php5-cgi processes appear and die within a 30 second period, sucking back 1.6GB of RAM then are killed.

It didn't show up in my logs because it was not a single process sucking up the 1.6GB, it was 60-someodd processes.  And the oom killer doesn't kill it, something in Apache is killing it.

I finally found it when I adjusted my process logging to get the breadth of processes and wrote some awk scripts to add up their memory.  It seems obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

What does the syslog say? Is there any hint that the kernel is killing off processes because of OOM?

How big is the swap? Have you adjusted any kernel in the `vm.` namespace?

How much is "a bunch"?

What happens in those 30 minutes? What does `vmstat -SM 3` look like?

Perhaps most importantly: What applications are you running, (how) are they affected by this?

Comment: The 'bunch' is the 1.6GB.  It's odd.  The Swap is 2GB, but mostly unused (50MB occasionally shows up in there).  vmstat -SM 3 would be hard to run in a timely fashion.  When the system experiences this, sometimes the terminal is unresponsive.   Applications:  They freeze, we occasionally get Bug: Soft Lockup in the syslog, and their load values get artifically inflated.  Everything slowly comes back.

Comment: I suspect the load afterwards is a backlog of activity.  Base load on the server is a steady 2-3% with a 5% average load.  I recently brought that down from higher figures by removing spamd, changing awstats jobs etc.  The server is a shared web host with pop3 and imap on Dovecot.  It's overtaxed, but this kind of performance probelm and this kind of weird memory behaviour is abnormal, even for a server which is under steady load.

Comment: Oh and no hint of the OOM killer.... lots of memory free.

Comment: Given all this extra information, I would say that the primarily active process is switching, from say `httpd` to `dovecot`. At this time you will see a lot of swapping going around, but only for this limited time.

My suggestion is that you disable the OOM killer, and hence Linux weird memory management, and make it a little easier for you to foretell what will happen by setting `vm.overcommit_memory = 2`

That way you'll see when your applications are actually running out of memory, or don't have enough to begin with -- the moment you start them.